# An strongly open set which is not measurable in the weak operator topology.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a non-separable Hilbert space and $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. Let $J$ be a proper subset in $I$.

Let us put $$E=\{x\in B(H): \lVert xe_j\rVert <1: j\in J\}$$

One may check that  $E$ is an open set  in the strong operator topology but not in the weak operator topology.

**Question:** I feel $E$ is not in the sigma algebra generated  by the weak operator topology but have no evidence to prove it.